# Durandal dialog scrolling on overflow

Tags: durandal

Using version 2.1.0 of durandal I found a problem I am not able to fix it seems.

I'm using a dialog but the content is too big for the screen, the buttons - which are at the bottom of the screen - kind of fall off, under the screen.

This mostly comes from the fact that I use visible bindings using knockout the show and hide elements on the dialog making durandal position it wrong and/or not showing a scrollbar for the dialog/screen when it overflows.

Does anyone know how to solve this by either getting a scrollbar or repositioning it on the screen?

I have tried the reposition method but to no success.
Moreover I tried both of these:

[Responsive dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394022/responsive-dialog-in-durandal-2-1)

[Durandal modal dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017341/durandal-modal-dialog-context-that-allows-scrolling-on-mobile-devices)

Both did not help out and I'm still stuck on this.
Anyone got any idea how to get the scrollbar on the dialog or on the screen so I can actually see my buttons by scrolling? Or is there a better way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you want

```
.modal-body {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 210px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/farizazmi/5Lnqurar/

Comment: I remember that overflow-y: auto created some problems for Android, or was it Windows Phone ... if you know for sure that scrolling will be needed set the value to "scroll" instead of auto, so you are on the safe side.

Comment: This does not work for me, it really only falls off when I show new elements that are not on the screen by default but in stead are shown by knockouts visibility bindings. He doesn't seem to be recalculating when the scrollbar should show.